# Print elevation of different coordinates from .hgt file

Tags: python-3, srtm, iteration, hgt

I am trying iterate through the data(elevation) from .hgt file. I have attached the codes which i used to get the elevation from the file.

```
from gmalthgtparser import HgtParser    
hgt_file='N09E076.hgt'
with HgtParser(hgt_file) as parser:
    alt = parser.get_elevation((9.666673719181665,76.30757542014408))
    print(alt)
```

The output of the above code will be : (1200, 1108, 7)

So here the input is given by the user with exact longitude and latitude. I want it to iterate through all the coordinates under some range and print each coordinates elevation and it should be saved as an excel file.

Comment: Can you [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/319200/edit) your question to clarify what you mean by "*iterate through all the coordinates under some range*".

Comment: i mean i need to get the values by iterating through different longitudes and latitudes. Those values given in the parser.get_elevation is longitude and latitude respectively....so for different longitudes and latitudes i will get the elevation according to that

Comment: Yes but what lon/lats do you want to iterate through?  Where do you get them from? It's basically `for lon, lat in [(lon, lat), (lon, lat), (etc...)]:`

Comment: i am trying to give for loops for longitudes and latitudes so that for different location i get the height

Comment: Yes I understand that. I'll ask again, *what* lon/lats do you want to iterate through and *where* do you get them from? As I said, it's just `for lon, lat in [(a lon, a lat), (another lon, another lat), (etc...)]:` then `alt = parser.get_elevation((lon, lat))`

Comment: Its the SRTM data which is in hgt format. N09E076 this is 9 deg north and 76 deg east....so i gave the coordinates 9.666673719181665,76.30757542014408. While putting these values, i get the elevation/ height as 7. Like these i need to get height of other locations too

Comment: I understand that, you have made that clear. But since you won't answer my questions about your lon/lats (your"other locations"), all I can say is use a `for` loop like I commented previously.

Comment: can we give it randomly within a range?, because its just to for the demonstration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random
from gmalthgtparser import HgtParser    

hgt_file='N09E076.hgt'
minlat, minlon = 9, 76

# 50 random samples
with HgtParser(hgt_file) as parser:
    for i in range(50):  # 50 samples
        lat = random.uniform(minlat, minlat+1)
        lon = random.uniform(minlon, minlon+1)
        alt = parser.get_elevation((lat,lon))
        print(lat, lon, alt)

# Iterate over all the elevation values inside a file.

with HgtParser(hgt_file) as parser:
   for alt in parser.get_value_iterator():
       print(alt)
```